# How to get values of cells of rows other than that of current row while iterating a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to find the values of other cells of a table other than the one in which I am currently at. I am doing something as -

```
$('#poTable  > .bodyTr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find(".variant").val() == productVariantId){
        alert('Cannot add mutiple rows for same Variant');
        value= false;
        $(this).find(".variant").val('');
        return value;
    }
});
```

but this takes the row also in which I have .`live` implemented hence comparing its own value with itself resulting in `false`. I have to exclude the current rows value while checking the same value is not with the other rows.

Comment: Could you show the context of that code? If it's in an event handler where `this` is the clicked cell you could say something like `$('#poTable > .bodyTr').not(this).each(...`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this code is inside a handler where this is the element selected...

```
$('#poTable > .bodyTr').not(this).each(...);
```

Comment: `$('#poTable > .bodyTr').not(this).each(function(){
   if(!$(this).find(".variant").is("input")){
    alert($(this).find(".variant").get(0).innerHTML);
   }
   else{
    alert($(this).find(".variant").val());
   }
   
  });`

I tried this one for three rows. But got alerts for all three. I am not supposed to get alert for the third row as I was in the third one. What changes would prevent it?

Comment: Please share more of the code.  In order to help you we need to see what 'this' is.